# Calculation the flow of some vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Compute the flow of each of the following vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$

a) $V=y\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$

b) $X= x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$

c) $W= x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ y \frac{ \partial}{\partial 2y}$

d) $Y= x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$

I could solve them but I have forgoten how to solve differential equation :

For part (a) :

$\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ so $\gamma^{'}(t) = (\gamma(t) , (x^{'}(t) , y^{'}(t))$, so $(\gamma(t) , (y(t) , 1)$, so I need to solve the following differential equation for obtaining $\gamma(t)$:

\begin{cases}
x^{'}=y \\ y^{'}=1 
\end{cases}
For (b) is this :

\begin{cases}
x=x^{'} \\ y^{'}=-y
\end{cases}

For (c) we have :

\begin{cases}
x^{'}=x \\ y^{'}=2y
\end{cases}

For (d) we have :

\begin{cases}
x^{'}=x \\ y^{'}=y
\end{cases}

I just need to solve the above differential equation for solving. could anyone help me solve those differential equations?

Comment: You can solve $(b),(c),$ and $(d)$ right away since they're separable. For $(a)$ note that we have $x''=1$